# Where the debug info of static library is merged after linking with MSVC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compilation, debug-information

Let's say that I have static library which generates it's debug info in `pdb` format with `/Zi` option.  Next let's link it into executable which also generates its debug info in `pdb`.

1. Am I right that the debug info of the static library will be merged into `pdb` of the executable?
2. If the library generates it's debug info directly in `lib` file with `/Z7` option, but the executable still uses `pdb` where the debug info from the static library will be merged? Into the `pdb` file or directly in executable?